# iOS PjSIP VoIP app does not run in background after 10 minutes in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, voip, ios7.1, pjsip

I am unable to keep the VoIP app in background.

Currently I am using pjsip version 2.2.1. I want to keep the app in background for long time similar to Skype. But the app terminates after 10 minutes while using in iOS8. I had tested the app on iOS 7.x and I was able to receive incoming calls even after the app stays in background for 30 minutes.

I am using setKeepAliveTimeout handler (timeout value 600 sec) to keep the app's VoIP service in background. What can I do to keep the app's VoIP service alive in background after 10 minutes?

I am using Keepalive in background,

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL handler: ^{

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        }];
```

Comment: Try setting the keep alive timeout to a smaller value, say 300 seconds, which also happens to be the default value. Also try using TCP instead of UDP for the signalling.

Comment: What are the contents of `-keepAlive`? Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:), the keep alive handler only has 10 seconds to execute, otherwise the app will be terminated.  Also, the keep alive handler is invoked on the main thread, so no need to call `-performSelectorOnMainThread:...`.  Just call `[self keepAlive];` and it'll have the same effect.

Comment: And you should be using `UIMinimumKeepAliveTimeout` rather than `KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL`.  If the minimum timeout ever changed, so would that value of this constant (requiring no additional work on your part).